# Ubuntu Equivalent of Unix Command cp -n

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, unix

A piece of software software I need to install on my Ubuntu Hardy system has a Makefile which includes the command `cp -n`.

However, I get an error stating that `-n` is an invalid option.

The command will work on a Mac terminal but I need it to work on Ubuntu.

Does anyone know the equivalent command for Ubuntu?

Comment: Step up a level from the immediate question -- look harder for linux (or debian or ubuntu) installation instructions. Unless this is a very niche or internal tool, there are likely installation instructions which will work better on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4):

In FreeBSD (it's like Mac OS X in many ways) the option `-n` means "Do not overwrite an existing file." I think that in ubuntu you can use the `-u` flag that means update that copy only if destination is older than the source or if destination is missing.

Answer (score 1):

The `-n` flag means "no clobbering" (do not replace existing files when copying). You can use `cp -i` to have `cp` ask whether a file should be overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

`cp` in GNU coreutils 7.6 certainly has the `-n` option. Use `cp --version` to verify the version of cp that is being used.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you're using cp in an automated build script, the bash rewrite would simply be:

```
cp -n src dest
```

to

```
if [ ! -e dest ]; then
    cp -f src dest
fi
```